# Example of an infinite abelian group having a non-cyclic finite subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

Give example (if exists) of an infinite abelian group having a non-cyclic finite subgroup . Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest non-cyclic finite group is the Klein four-group $V = C_2 \times C_2$.

So,we can just take $\mathbb Z \times V$.

More generally, take any nontrivial finite abelian group $G$ and take $\mathbb Z \times G \times G$.

Comment: so the finite  non-cyclic subgroup is $V \times \{0\}$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev, $0 \times V$, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Just take your favourite non-cyclic finite abelian group, and take the direct product with the group of integers.